# How can I get my http and subscription to work on client with graphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I finally finished my backend with apollo.
Now I moved to the frontend.

I made it work with the normal http connection and fetched some messages from the server (chat app).
Now I also tried to connect the subscription link to it (which was very confusing in itself because there are a few examples outside and everybody does it a bit differently, but neither worked).

So here is how my index file looks on react frontend:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:4000/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
});
// Create an http link:
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
});
const link = ApolloLink.from([httpLink, wsLink]);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I also tried different methods for example with split from apollo-link like this:

```
const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
);
```

I also tried it with ApolloClient from apollo-boost instead of apollo-client.

Can somebody please help me out, because I can't get it to work.
Error message is always:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

If you want to see the full code: https://github.com/SelfDevTV/graphql-simple-chat

Comment: different port - CORS problem?

Comment: It's on the same port. Link to websocket is: `ws://localhost:4000/graphql`
Cors is activated and the normal http connection works fine.
Maybe you could take a look at the `index.js` file in the root, where I set up everything on the server. Maybe the error is somewhere there, but I can't find it. Made everything like from the docs.

Comment: go for inspirations [here](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/modules/core/common/createApolloClient.ts) and [here](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/modules/core/server-ts/api/subscriptions.ts)

Comment: Fixed it somehow. I don't know what it exactly was, but suddenly it magically just worked. Thanks anyway :)